# Move positioning of x axis labels in ggplot without hjust or vjust

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using some sample data from BLS below, I'm trying to make a faceted plot of spending categories by income bracket.

Because some of the label names are long, I have them rotated 90 degrees. I have been using hjust and vjust to move around the labels a bit, but I am wondering if there are more systematic ways to have the labels "snap" to the axis in ways that are less discretionary.

The two things I'd ideally want to do:

1. Align the text so that they're all the way to the x axis line (I guess this would be right-justified if you tilt your head?).
2. It looks like each x axis label is slightly off-centered without using vjust, to the right just slightly, for reasons I'm unsure about. I've tried to center them a bit with vjust but is there a way to force center them on the x axis ticks?

Code:

```
ggplot(d_ex, aes(x = spend_type, y = amt_yearly, fill = spend_type)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~bls_income_cat,
             nrow = 3) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1,
                                  vjust = -1))
```

Data:

```
d_ex <- structure(list(spend_type = c("Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", 
"Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Food", "Housing", "Housing", 
"Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", "Housing", 
"Housing", "Entertainment", "Entertainment", "Entertainment", 
"Entertainment", "Entertainment", "Entertainment", "Entertainment", 
"Entertainment", "Entertainment"), amt_yearly = c(5337, 5040, 
6038, 7154, 8170, 9336, 11732, 14021, 17678, 12816, 14429, 17442, 
19487, 20553, 23523, 28337, 35588, 49709, 1164, 1401, 2145, 1871, 
2768, 3402, 3946, 6349, 8856), bls_income_cat = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), levels = c("All", 
"Less than $15,000", "$15,000 to $29,999", "$30,000 to $39,999", 
"$40,000 to $49,999", "$50,000 to $69,999", "$70,000 to $99,999", 
"$100,000 to $149,999", "$150,000 to $199,999", "$200,000 and more"
), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Personally I would simply go for a horizontal barchart, i.e. swap the mapping on x and y. But to center you could simply use `vjust=.5`.

Comment: And to align the labels so that their right edge touches the x axis is `hjust = 1`, as you have already